# Prev and next button

Tags: javascript, navigation

My website has previous and next buttons. When the page loads id like the previous button to be invisible.(on the first panel)
After the user clicks the next button (to go to 2nd panel), id like the previous button to appear.

Is there some javascript that will do this?

Answer (score 3):

Add a CSS `display: none;` to the Previous button then add an `onclick` event to the button:

```
<input id="next" type="button" name="next" onclick="document.getElementById('previous').style.display = 'block';
" />
```

Where `#previous` = the ID of your previous button.

If you are having trouble, see this link for 7 ways to hide elements using JavaScript:
http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/

Comment: do i add the onclick event to the next button?

Comment: Yes indeedy, you can reverse the code and put it on the Previous button as well - just replace the getElementById('pervious') to getElementById('next') ^_^